# There is a spacing between adjacent cell of the deleting rows when using deleteRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, objective-c

There is a spacing between adjacent cell of the deleting rows when using deleteRowsAtIndexPaths. this only appear when the delete cell's height is small than the above cell's.

Thanks for trying to help!

```
        NSMutableArray *deleteArray = [NSMutableArray array];

        for (int i = 1; i < [speakerlist count]+1; i++) {

            [deleteArray addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:indexPath.section]];
        }

        [CATransaction begin];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [showSpeakerlistCell.imageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI)];
        [CATransaction commit];
```

[image]

I have tried another way with an independent demo project, and it worked, but it   have some strange animation when I pull to my project.

I have build a [project](https://github.com/besniba/ExpansionTableTest.git) to compare:

it fine when I using the ViewController, it's not fine when I suing ViewController_02 which's same code as ViewController.(enable below code in the project)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

//    ViewController_02 *vc = [[ViewController_02 alloc] init];
//    [self.window setRootViewController:vc];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: UITableViewRowAnimationFade is better for delete operations.

Comment: it looks a little better, but still can see the spacing

Answer (score 0):

You have to use UITableview functions beginUpdates/endUpdates for grouping of animations. Modified code will be

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[tableView endUpdates];

[UIview animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [showSpeakerlistCell.imageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI)];
}];
```

Comment: eh , it should be write like this, but it do nothing different

Answer (score 0):

I find a way, Using  UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic animation when call deleteRowsAtIndexPaths and  insertRowsAtIndexPaths. and I have update my demo code https://github.com/besniba/ExpansionTableTest.git